# jquery slidetoggle template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap and make one row with 2 column and one button , I want to do when i click on the button will show 4 column instead of 2 column.

JQuery

> $('#more_service').on('click',function(){
>
> ```
>   $('.service_container').slideToggle('slow',function(){      
>
>           var template = $('item_template').html();
>           $('.service_wrapper').html(template);       
>
>               });
>       });
> ```

html

> Creative Service
>
> ```
>       <div class="row">
>           <div class="span4">
>               <img src="img/web-developing.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
>               <h3 class="red-text  text-center">Creative Service</h3>
>               <p class="webdev text-center">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
>           </div>
>           <div class="span4">
>               <img src="img/branding.png" class="center-block" alt="" />
>               <h3 class="red-text  text-center">Branding</h3>
>               <p class="webdev text-center">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
>           </div>          </div>          <div class="row">
>           <div class="span4">
>               <img src="img/web-developing.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
>               <h3 class="red-text  text-center">Creative Service</h3>
>               <p class="webdev text-center">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
>           </div>
>           <div class="span4">
>               <img src="img/branding.png" class="center-block" alt="" />
>               <h3 class="red-text  text-center">Branding</h3>
>               <p class="webdev text-center">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
>           </div>          </div>
>
>
>                           </div>  </script>
> ```

Comment: $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" value="value" />');

You can dynamically element like this. I used text box you can add as you want.

Comment: Where are more_service, service_container, item_template and service_wrapper on your html?

Answer (score 0):

$('item_template').html(); is an element in your code like a class or an ID? If so, you need to add a dot or a hashtag like:

```
$('item_template').html();
```

becomes

```
$('#item_template').html(); or $('.item_template').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

if `item_template` is id use `#` if it is class use `.` and use `innerHTML`:

```
var template = $('#item_template').innerHTML;
```

Comment: it is working my problem is next time when i click on the button not working.